# Нужно получить цену каждого дня на графике

Tags: python, html, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Есть сайт https://investfunds.ru/etf/697/ с графиком цены, из него нужно вытащить цену каждого дня. Но копаясь в коде странице этого источника, я нахожу цену только за последние дни.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда тогда этот сайт берет цену актива? Мне это нужно для парсинга цены.

Comment: ваш код где? что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Сформулируйте чётче. Что вам нужно - цена актива за текущий день?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
# import json
import requests


url = 'https://investfunds.ru/etf/697/'
date_from = '19.09.2020'
payload = {
    'action': 'chartData', 
    'data_key': 'close', 
    'date_from': date_from
    }

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
```

В ответ прилетит словарь с данными, среди них - котировки с 19.09.2020 по сегодняшний день:

```
>>> len(r.json()['data'])
125
```

Даты будут в timestamp:

```
>>> print(r.text)
{
    "name":"FinEx USA UCITS ETF (USD)",
    "tooltip":{"valueDecimals":2,"xDateFormat":"%d.%m.%Y"},
    "data":[
        [1600635600000,4514],
        [1600722000000,4563],
        [1600808400000,4619],

        ...

        [1615928400000,5361],
        [1616014800000,5356],
        [1616101200000,5311]
    ]
}
```

Или, если нужна выборка не до текущей даты, добавьте `date_to` в `payload`:

```
payload = {
    'action': 'chartData', 
    'data_key': 'close', 
    'date_from': '12.12.2020',
    'date_to': '19.12.2020'
    }
```

В итоге в `data` - список с пятью датами и ценами закрытия:

```
>>> len(r.json()['data'])
5
>>> print(r.json()['data'])
[
    [1607893200000, 4959], 
    [1607979600000, 4986], 
    [1608066000000, 5006], 
    [1608152400000, 4985], 
    [1608238800000, 4996]
]
```

Comment: Я новичок, подскажите используя ваш код, как мне получать цены не посегодняшний день, а вводить период, например с 12.09.2020 по 19.12.2020 день и получать это в массив

Comment: @ЕгорКопица добавил в ответ