# Нужно выводить элементы через одну итерацию

Tags: python, циклы, for

Есть список списков:

```
l = [[1607893200000, 4959],   
     [1607979600000, 4986], 
     [1608066000000, 5006], 
     [1608152400000, 4985], 
     [1608238800000, 4996]
    ]
```

Нужно написать код, который будет выводить:

```
4959
4986
5006
4985
4996
```

Comment: Во-первых, это не словарь, а список списков. Во-вторых, это не итерация, а каждый четный элемент подсписка. В-третьих, ваш код где?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обработайте ответ сервера, выделите data:

```
data = r.json()['data']
```

и, итерируясь по списку, выводите второй элемент каждого:

```
for d in data:
    print(d[1])
```

выведет:

```
4959
4986
5006
4985
4996
```

Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1259343/420098

Comment: `json.loads(r.content)` --> `r.json()` ;)